# Reversing a string from first principles - what's wrong?

Tags: c++, string, reverse

I am learning how to reverse strings (i.e., write backwards) from first principles in C++. I devised the following code that is meant to take in a string from the user, reverse it, and print it out. However, it fails to compile—Visual Studio gives me an error "string subset out of range". What is wrong?

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string example;

    getline(cin, example);

    int i = 0;

    while (example[i] != '\0') 
    {
        i++;
    }

    int n=0;
    string reverse;

    while (n < i)
    {
        reverse[n] = example[i - n - 1];
        n++;
    }

    cout << reverse << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am targeting C++17.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: I hardly doubt VS would validate string index at compile time, please be accurate with discpription - do you get compile or runtime rror?

Comment: I don't think that applies to my case since the names of my two strings are different. You are probably thinking of the instance when the reversed string is given the same name as the original one, right? @Bathsheba

Comment: I get a runtime error @Slava

Comment: You do not resize `reverse` to the size of of example so any `n` would be out of range. Why don’t you use `push_back`?

Comment: Like @t.niese said, your reverse is an empty string so you cannot index it, otherwise you get an access out of bound.

Comment: Thanks - I suspected the error is along these lines; how do I resize appropriately? @t.niese

Comment: That depends on the final use case. Your example is kind of arbitrary as you wouldn’t revers a string in that way anyway. But either on construction as shown in one of the answers or using `resize` or use `push_back` in combination with `reserve`.

Answer (score 2):

`reverse[n]` causes the string out of index problem. You just created the string and its size is zero. Here's how you fix it:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::getline;

int main()
{
    string example;
    getline(cin, example);
    int i = 0;
    while (example[i] != '\0') 
    {
        i++;
    }

    int n=0;
    string reverse(example.size(), 0);

    while (n < i)
    {
        reverse[n] = example[i - n - 1];
        n++;
    }

    cout << reverse << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, there's still a lot wrong about this code. For instance, storing the size of the string in `int` is a bad idea. Use `std::string::size_type` instead. And `std::string::size` already gives you the size, no need to count it. Also, consider using a for loop here:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::getline;

int main()
{
    string example;
    getline(cin, example);
    string reverse(example.size(), 0);
    for (string::size_type n = 0; n != example.size(); ++n)
    {
        reverse[n] = example[example.size() - n - 1];
    }

    cout << reverse << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Having said that, here's how I'd implement it:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::getline;

int main()
{
  auto example = string();
  getline(cin, example);
  auto reverse = string(example.crbegin(), example.crend());

  cout << reverse << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Make sure to familiarize yourself with [reverse iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) if you are not already.

Comment: Thanks. Why is it a bad idea to store the length of a string as an integer? @Ayxan

Comment: `int` has a max value limit. You can check your implementations limit by using [INT_MAX](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits). If the string is larger than that maximum, integer overflows. `std::size_t` on the other hand is guaranteed to be large enough to represented the size of the string. No matter how big it is

Comment: `size_t` also has a max value limit. The important part is that the max value of `int` could be different from `size_t` (the max of `int` could in theory also be larger then the one of `size_t`) and that `size_t` is unsigned and `int` is signed. You should use `numeric_limits` instead of `INT_MAX`. And while it is true that `std::string::size_type` is `size_t` one most of the implementations it is - afaik - not guaranteed to be `size_t`. So the appropriate type for `n` is strictly speaking `std::string::size_type`.

Comment: size_t does have a max value, but it is guaranteed to be large enough to represent the size of the string. And since [A type whose size cannot be represented by std::size_t is ill-formed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t), it is always fine to use `std::size_t` instead of `std::string::size_type` or any other `size_type`, no?

Comment: In most cases, it would be safe to assume that the maximum of `size_type` is not larger than `std::size_t`. But let's assume that maximum of `std::size_t` would be exactly the maximum number of byte that can be allocated on a given system, then `size_t` still  `[...]can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type[...]`, but an `std::vector<bool>` where one entry might only require one bit, could then store `size_t` times 8 elements. And custom containers could have distributed memory where `size_type` could in theory much larger.

Comment: So for most std containers, you can assume that `std::size_t` is valid to use on a regular 32/64 bit System. You just should always keep in mind that this is not necessarily true.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is a special case and you're right in in this regard. Thanks for pointing out. I'll edit the answer and switch `size_t` with `size_type` for maximum generality and portability.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem :  `reverse[n] = example[i - n - 1];`

As you have used string as data type, but are using character array syntax;

change it to :

```
`reverse += example[i - n - 1];
```

Complete code for reference :`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string example;

    getline(cin, example);

    int i = 0;

    while (example[i] != '\0') 
    {
        i++;
    }

    int n=0;
    string reverse;

    //cout << i << endl;

    while (n < i)
    {
        reverse += example[i - n - 1];
        n++;
    }

    cout << reverse << endl;

    return 0;
}
```